# Trigger Email from Marketing cloud when a record is added manually to DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, dataextensions, data, triggered-send

Built a DE and template and configured Trigger Send by selecting both respective DE and template.

I have activated the TSD, when I manually added a record in DE under Contact builder. the TSD did not trigger. To know the Trigger send is configured correctly I had used api to add record to DE. API call for same:

{
"To": {
"Address": "XXX",
"SubscriberKey": "XXX",
"ContactAttributes": {
"SubscriberAttributes": {
"EmailAddress": "XXX@XXX.com",
"SubscriberKey": "XXX"
}
}
}
}

When the call was trigger using Postman the TSD send a email, but when i added a record manually did not trigger.

Can you please suggest how to achieve the trigger of email send based on manual adding of records to DE.

Thanks
Joey

Comment: Hi Joey. This is not possible. You can only trigger a TSD email via the API. There is no “listener” on data extensions, allowing for triggering emails upon new records being added.

Comment: thank you @LukasLunow, i tried through import activity through automation. So the TSD will not respond to that as well?